# How to use route 53 to create subdomains that reference specific URLs of an EC2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, subdomain, amazon-route53, namecheap

I have an EC2 instance running Redmine and myPHPadmin at `https://myElasticIP/redmine` and `https://myElasticIP/phpmyadmin`.

I have a domain name registered with namecheap:  `myDomain.us`

Using Route 53, I have customized the DNS of `myDomain.us` (through the namecheap interface) to use the delegate NS's in Route 53, so going to `myDomain.us` will automatically reference `myelasticIP` instead.

**How do I get it so that going to `redmine.myDomain.us` references `https://myElasticIP/redmine` and `myphpadmin.myDomain.us` references `https://myElasticIP/myphpadmin`?** *(without using URL Frames or URL redirect...I want `x.myDomain.us` to remain in the address bar)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with DNS alone - you'll need to get some HTTP involved somewhere.

I'd just create two vhosts, one for `redmine.myDomain.us` and one for `myphpadmin.myDomain.us`, and just point their `DocumentRoot` to the correct location on your filesystem.

For instance, if this is your vhost for myDomain.us:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myDomain.us
    DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you'd create the following additional vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redmine.myDomain.us
    DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myphpadmin.myDomain.us
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myphpadmin
</VirtualHost>
```

Additionally, you'll need to create two new DNS names for the two new vhosts. DNS `CNAME` records should be created `redmine.myDomain.us` and `myphpadmin.myDomain.us`, both pointing to `myDomain.us`.

Comment: *DNS CNAME records should be created `redmine.myDomain.us` and `myphpadmin.myDomain.us`, both pointing to `myDomain.us`.*  Just to verify, should they point to the elastic IP or the domain name?

Comment: They should point to the domain name.

Comment: This is helping, but I still have an issue.  I am using the rewrite mod to force port 80 connections to be rewritten to https, `RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/redmine [R]`.  This is resulting in requests for `http://redmine.myDomain.us` to go to `https://redmine.myDomain.us/redmine`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post that as a separate question.